# Difference between using a pointer to assign a value/just assigning it normally?

Tags: c, pointers

What's the difference between these two:

x = x + 5

*y = *y + 5 (where *y points to address of x)

As far as I'm aware, both give the same value, and both change the contents in that memory address - so is there any actual difference? Why would you ever use a pointer in a situation like this when it requires an extra fetch?

Comment: one reason, you can pass pointers to functions and change the values they point to from there.

Comment: for large data types and functions, passing by reference can be a lot cheaper than passing by value.  Imagine passing in a 1MByte structure to a function by value...

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: You're right -- in a situation like this, you probably wouldn't use a pointer.  (This is one of the hard things about learning pointers -- many of the examples you come across are just completely useless.  They might show you, mechanically, how pointers "work", but they don't motivate any appreciation of what pointers are good for.)

Comment: One difference is that, at compilation time, the compiler may not know that `y` will point to `x` during execution. This would prevent it from doing some optimizations that it can do with `x = x + 5`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why would you ever use a pointer in a situation like this when it requires an extra fetch?

You wouldn't.

Here is a small example of how you can do some useful with pointers. Let's say that you want to write a function where you increment the argument by one. It cannot be done without pointers. It can look like this:

```
void inc(int *x) {
    *x = *x + 1;
}
```

Now, we can use this function like this:

```
int main() {
    int a = 5;
    printf("Value before: %d\n", a);        
    inc(&a); // The & is to send the address of the variable
    printf("Value after: %d\n", a);
}
```

This program would print this:

```
Value before: 5
Value after: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

One usually uses pointers when several portions of code shall share and operate on the same value, having changes made in one portion being reflected at another portion. This is in contrast to having a value just copied to different portions, thereby loosing the "connection" to the original value.

For operating on a shared value, for example, you could pass a pointer to an integral value to a function. This function may then directly change the "originally" passed value by dereferencing the pointer. In contrast, when passing an integral value "by value" to a function, the function will operate on a copy and will not have any chance to change the "original" value directly.

If the former or the latter is the right choice depends on whether you need to share a common state or you definitely want to decouple portions of code.